# How to work out total distinct values minus grouped distinct values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Given the sample table of:

```
+----+----------+---------+------+
| id | userName | storeId | cost |
+----+----------+---------+------+
|  1 | foo      |       1 |   10 |
|  2 | bar      |       1 |   10 |
|  3 | baz      |       5 |    5 |
|  4 | baz      |       3 |   20 |
|  5 | qux      |       1 |    5 |
|  6 | qux      |       4 |   20 |
|  7 | qux      |      15 |   30 |
|  8 | qux      |      17 |   40 |
|  9 | qux      |       3 |    5 |
| 10 | quux     |       6 |   20 |
+----+----------+---------+------+
```

I would like to work out how many people purchased at each store and how many did not. I want the report to display the results grouped by store.

I know the statement `select storeId, count(distinct username) as total from purchases group by storeId` provides me with how many people purchased in each store, but I want to subtract the result of the query `select count(distinct userName) from purchases;` in another column. I would expect the sample output to display as follows.

```
+---------+-----------+--------------+
| storeId | purchased | notPurchased |
+---------+-----------+--------------+
|       1 |         3 |            2 |
|       3 |         2 |            3 |
|       4 |         1 |            4 |
|       5 |         1 |            4 |
|       6 |         1 |            4 |
|      15 |         1 |            4 |
|      17 |         1 |            4 |
+---------+-----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOT condition with IN() function

Comment: this is a comment only, please providfe a sample code and show how it works

Answer (score 0):

As long a subse3lect gives back only only one,
you can use following

> ```
> SELECT 
>     storeId,
>     COUNT(DISTINCT username) AS total,
>     ((SELECT 
>             COUNT(DISTINCT userName)
>         FROM
>             purchases) - COUNT(DISTINCT username)) notPurchased
> FROM
>     purchases
> GROUP BY storeId
> ```
>
> ```
> storeId | total | notPurchased
> ------: | ----: | -----------:
>       1 |     3 |            2
>       3 |     2 |            3
>       4 |     1 |            4
>       5 |     1 |            4
>       6 |     1 |            4
>      15 |     1 |            4
>      17 |     1 |            4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d922bf824e64461ff6f908c84e13b769)*